# Pyspark/NiFi : Converting Multiline rows file to single line row file

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-nifi

I have a csv file which has records are in multiline like this

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7

1,2,3,4

,5,6,

7

1,2

3,4

,5,6,


7
```

I want to change the file like below -

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7

1,2,3,4,5,6,7

1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

I know pyspark can read such file with multiline :True option but I want to convert this file to single line rows which is the business use case. How can I do it. Technologies to be used are either Pyspark or NiFi. Thanks in advance

Comment: Whichever way you do it, I asume you have 7 fields per row in your dataset. So you have to read that 7 elements and ignore any newlines.

Answer (score 2):

In NiFi you could use a ScriptedReader to do this, but that takes custom code in a language like Groovy or Jython.

If you know the first row always has the right number of fields, you could parse the first "record" and save off the number of fields. Then you could continue to parse, ignoring whitespace, returning a new record each time the number of fields has been parsed.

If you don't know the first row has the total number of fields, you'd want to pass that in as a FlowFile attribute and use that to parse the fields.